# Database Error for duplicate entry

Tags: php, sql

I have a proper db connection where the database name is db-name,the table name is tb-name and  the field names are same as the form fields: name, phone, form no, address.

I would like to avoid duplicated form entries with the same "form no", if that happen I would like to show an error and show the form again.

Please help me,
thanks.

```
        <div class="cform">
          <center>
            <h2>New Water Meter Application Form</h2>
          </center>
          <form action="submit.php<?php if($formId != ''){ echo '?update='.$formId; } ?>" method="post" name="myform" class="compform" id="myform">
           <input type="hidden" name="UserName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['UserName']; ?>" />
           <ul>
             <div class="part1">
               <li>
                 <p>name:</p>
                 <input type="text" name="name" id="name"   />
               </li>
               <li>
                 <p>phone:</p>
                 <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /> 
               </li>
               <li>
                 <p>Form No.:</p>
                 <input type="text" name="FormNo" id="FormNo"  />
               </li>
               <li>
                 <p>address:</p>
                 <input type="text" name="address" id="address" /> 
               </li>
             </ul>
             <input type="Submit" name="submit" id="Submit" value="submit" class="submit"  />
          </form>
```

Comment: post some code please.

Comment: Again no code. Try to check whether that record exists or not.If exists show the error message. In the database , you can make those fields unique, so that if you want to insert again , it will through error. Need more ?? Post some code

Comment: Have you set the PRIMARY KEY: for Form No Field in Table?
If not First Set it to restrict the Duplication.
Second Try to put some code so, We can analyze your code and make some condition to Identify duplicate and Return Suitable Message.

Because this is Off-Topic Discussion without Code...

Comment: but i have another field which i set, form id is primary key

Comment: Give your Table Structure to get an Idea.

Comment: i set form no to UNIQUE , in my form duplicate form no, is not submitting but it not showing any error it just blank page shows when someone pout duplicate entry that's my problem.......i show a Waring page instead of blank page and redirect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement your INSERT Query should be like this. I hope it is helpful

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
(name, phone, FormNo, address)
VALUES('MyName', '123132', '5', 'xyz xyz')
WHERE FormNo != (SELECT FormNo FROM TABLE_NAME)
```

Or
If

```
SELECT FormNo FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE FormNo = "5"
```

Then
Return Error Message then Entry Available.
Else

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
(name, phone, FormNo, address)
VALUES('MyName', '123132', '5', 'xyz xyz')
```